# Nested quotes preg_replace regex

Tags: php, regex

I currently have the following regex:

```
\[quote="([^"]+)"\]([^[]+)\[\/quote\]
```

Which matches `[quote="author"]text[/quote]` in a string and captures `author` and `text` to convert it to a formatted div quote:

```
$p_text = preg_replace('/\[quote="([^"]+)"\]([^[]+)\[\/quote\]/', '<div class="quote"><strong class="quote-author">$1 wrote:</strong><br>$2</div>', $p_text);
```

However I want to be able to nest it once, like this:

```
[quote="b"]

    [quote="a"]
        Original text
    [/quote]

Reply to quote a
[/quote]

Reply to quote b
```

Here's how I want it to look:

[image]

Here's how it currently looks with the code above:

[image]

How can I nest the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve it from inside out with your current regex by using a loop.

```
$pattern = '/\[quote="([^"]+)"\]([^[]+)\[\/quote\]/';
$replace = '<div class="quote"><strong class="quote-author">' .
           '$1 wrote:</strong><br>$2</div>';
do {
  $p_text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $p_text, -1, $replace_count);
} while($replace_count > 0);
```

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/507548). If you need a [recursive regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) for whatever reason, [see this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jD4xD5/1).